# How to store and retrieve window state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, local-storage

I'm trying to write functions for storing and retrieving window state but cannot figure out how to do that. The idea is that user could make at any time a "snapshot" of the screen and with next login to the app he could retrieve it back, also he can store as many snapshots as he want.
For example: on the page I have 4 different closed panels with some kind of filters and 6 different tabs with grid inside (by default the first tab is opened). Now let's say, I have opened 2 of 4 panels, set some filters and worked with 5th tab. I want to be able to store whole window state (For example "My state 1"), and when I logged in at next time, just choose "My state 1" and get back my window state.
I already store and retrieve all grid properties in DB with next functions:

Store:

```
 $scope.state = {}
 $scope.saveStateString = function(store) {
        $scope.state = JSON.stringify($scope.gridApi.saveState.save(store));
        // console.log("function save state string")
   };
```

Retrieve

```
    if(objNode.folderId){
       eventService.singleFilter(nodeId)
             .then(function (res) {
                   if (res.body){
       $scope.restoreStateString(JSON.parse(res.body));
              }
           });
        }
   else if (typeof objNode.folderId === "undefined"){
         return false
    }

   $scope.restoreStateString = function(restore) {
         $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore( $scope, restore );
     };
```

For now I'm trying to store window state in localstorage and do next:

```
 var storeValue = null;
        var keyName = null;
        var _window = {};


        $scope.storeWorkspace = function (){

            for (prop in window)
                _window[prop] = window[prop];

            storeValue = JSON.stringify(_window)

            keyName = prompt("put your key name");
            localStorage.setItem(keyName, storeValue);
        };
```

but I get this error

> angular.js:13708 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       at Object.stringify (native)

I clearly understand, why I'm getting this error, it cause JSON doesn't accept circular objects - objects which reference themselves also I see from 
`console.log(_window)` how the "window" has many objects inside, so I decided to ask:
How to store and retrieve window state?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting from `window`? Seems like a strange place to look for state of your own application

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, I'm waiting behavior like from $scope.$watch, you are watching for state of your variable and can store diff states of it and then get it back

Comment: You simply need an angular service that stores all your app state. Then whenever state gets changed store  it. Would have nothing to do with `window`

Comment: @charlietfl, sounds like a good news for me, could you give me link on example?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how to use services. Also several localStorage modules that will take care of getting/setting for you

Comment: @charlietfl I'm sorry but I can't find anything by your references

Comment: I want to do the very same thing as the OP for use in making a data entry system where the user can save a database snapshot of their browser state using innerHTML *and serialize the JavaScript state. I'm just guessing but I think this might be important in trying to interact with the saved document. This data entry would be for looking up info on a lot of external .edu sites and saving the school calendars' html. I like the original idea better.

Comment: @andruo11 the only one way how could we make it is to split our page on sections and store each section as variable statement in angular and send to the server, then by request return it and render view base on that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vast majority of values stored on the `window` object are simply not serializable.  You will not be able to use `JSON` for this.  You should instead track all changes you make to `window` and store those in a separate JSON object as **POJO**s.  Alternatively, you can copy the initial `window` object when your application starts and then only store the differences between the current `window` object and the original copy.

In any case, this is probably going to be a hunt of trial and error, depending on what libraries you are using, and how they are using global variables.  You will probably find you need to manually filter out some stuff when you serialize.  Best practices would suggest *nothing* should write to the `window` object.  If you have things writing to the `window` object, you're probably dealing with badly behaving code.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, so you suggest next. Follow for each panel and tab state and then store it as 10 different JSON objects, right?

Comment: @antonyboom that would be overkill. You most likely only need one main state object

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix application data and resources to store, its huge, hard to reuse and will lead to running into other issues.

Keep it simple!

Construct appState object with what you required to reload the views

```
var appState ={config:{}, data:{}};
```

Store it in internalStorage / sessionStorage based on how long you to retain forever vs per session

```
localStorage.setItem("appState", appState);
```

On initial app start logic, load data from internalStorage / sessionStorage or server and you may modify existing controller code for binding it to the view.

```
getApplicationData(){
 var appState = localStorage.getItem("appState");//get it from browser storage
if(!appState)
   //get it from server
return appState;
}
```

This is more robust and performant approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not try to store the whole `window`.** Store your application's state in a separate object, e.g. `state`, which you can then attach to the global object if you absolutely have to:

```
window.state = {}; // your application's state goes here

var serializedState = JSON.stringify(window.state); // To be put into localStorage
```

Make sure that all the information you need to rebuild your app during the next launch is contained in this object, and nothing more than that. Avoid global state where possible.

Also make sure that your `state` object only contains serializable data. [E.g. functions or symbols cannot be serialzied to a JSON string and will get lost in the process.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)

Comment: thank you fro your explanation, I felt that store the whole window state isn't good idea