# Javascript, window[] undefined when pop-up is not closed between button presses

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code opens a pop-up with Javascript

If I close the pop-up between pressing on each button, the data gets sent to the pop-up correctly, andinside the pop-up's javascript code I can read it with

```
window.onload = () => {
    addAnotherTable(window["dataarray"]);
}
```

However, if I first open the pop-up and without closing it, then press on another button, the `window["dataarray"]` variable becomes undefined.
However, inside the main `AddTable` function, `v_popup["dataarray"]` still gets set to `sub_array`.

Why does `window["dataarray"]` become undefined if I don't close the pop-up and how can I fix this?

```
function addTable(result, indices) {
    indices = [2, 3, 6, 2, 4, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 12, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 12, 13, 1, ]; //for testing
     counter = 0;
    low = [];
    high = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.innerHTML = result[counter][0];
        btn.className = "button-28";
        var low = counter;
        var high = indices[i] + counter;
        var sub_array = result.slice(low, high);

        (function (sub_array) {
            btn.onclick = function () {
                var v_popup = window.open("popup.html", 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=700,left=50,top=50,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');
                v_popup["dataarray"] = sub_array;
            }
        })(sub_array);

        counter += indices[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `addAnotherTable` do?

Comment: where you doing this? on web server or from local disk?

Comment: I think you're losing `window` object when you are opening the popup, that's why I recommend looking into state management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend using `window` for state management,
here are some examples of better state management.

simple:
[How to store and retrieve window state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314121/how-to-store-and-retrieve-window-state)

fancier:
https://dev.to/vijaypushkin/dead-simple-state-management-in-vanilla-javascript-24p0

Also here is a article about how to manage popups properly to avoid running into such issues: https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/vanilla-javascript-modal-pop-up/